# Visual studio 2017 dotnet core cli how to debug

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

1. I have VS2017 installed with .net core 2.0.3 sdk installed.
2. i created a .net core console application with following code -

   ```
       Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

       Console.Read();

       Console.WriteLine("test");
   ```
3. right click on solution and publish using debug setting.
4. go to publishoutput open cmd(admin) at that path and run command **dotnet "dllname"**
5. go to visual studio click on attach to process select **Managed (v4.6, v4.5, v4.0) code** attach to dotnet.exe
6. VS goes in debugging state but none of the break point is hit.

How can i debug a .net core console application using VS2017? what am i missing in above points?

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was able to fix this by adding this entry in csproj file -

```
<DebugType>portable</DebugType>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, you could mark it as answer to make it more noticeable.